# How do I check jQuery uncheck radio button?

Tags: jquery

Hello I'm using following for checked of radio button and remove class now I want to apply same for unchecked and `addClass` what is changes is my following jQuery line for unchecked radio?

```
$("#address_show:checked").closest('.display_address').find('.ps-btn-show-address').removeClass('hide_address');
```

Comment: `$("#address_show:not(:checked)")`

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if ($("#address_show:not(:checked)") {
 // Do what you want here.
}
```